# SET component in ODI when using spark streaming

Tags: python, spark-streaming, oracle-data-integrator

I am creating a mapping in ODI using spark streaming. One problem is that previously when running batch using Oracle technology, my logic had a union step and I used ODI's SET component. However, in spark streaming mode it does not work. Is there any solution to this problem?

I need an alternative to implementing the logic of ODI's SET component using spark streaming.